# Netbeans 6.9 to SQL Server 2008 R2: "cannot resolve collation conflict..."

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on my local workstation but keep getting an error.
In Netbeans 6.9, in the New Entity Classes from Database wizard, I choose to Create a New Database Connection, Direct URL entry, select the SQL Server 2005 entry, enter the user name and password and the enter the JDBC URL (jdbc:sqlserver://myhost\sqlexpress:1234;databaseName=contoso).  That leads to this error:

[image]

I'm using the sqljdbc4.jar driver from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=%20a737000d-68d0-4531-b65d-da0f2a735707&displaylang=en).  What am I doing wrong?

However, despite this error, on the Services tab, I can open my the Databases node and see my SQL Server database instance with all the databases listed.  I can even issue a query against the contoso database and get results.  So the problem seems to be with the Wizard.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The server's collation is different from database's collation.

Comment: Please share some more information about this error, and post a solution, in addition to your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.netbeans.org/topic29593.html

Also there seems to be a bug creating entity class from database using Netbean 6.9 and SQL server 2008 R2

The thread is from July 2010 but I am still having same issue so you may want to search a bit and see if rollback to netbean 6.8 where people say it works fine in that version.

But this has nothing to do with your error message though just wanted to give you heads up.